# How to wrap lines in vanilla SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, jdbc

I have an `import.sql` for prepopulating the database for Arquillian tests. Some lines are unreadably long, and I would like to format them into several lines. Unfortunately I was unable to find any usefult advice - I have only found examples that are not meant for vanilla SQL, but rather for strings representing SQL in different programming languages.

I have tried wild guessing, separating the lines by pressing Return or inserting different characters between them - `\`, `/`, `_`, `&` and `+` but nothing worked. When Hibernate picks up and executes the file, a `JdbcSQLException` is thrown:

```
JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO KVS_MIPO(LSTORT, LOGIN, NAME, LANR)/[*] "; expected "DIRECT, SORTED, DEFAULT, VALUES, SET, (, SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement:
```

The original line works fine:

```
insert into KVS_MIPO(LSTORT, LOGIN, NAME, LANR) values ('123456789', 'x123456789', 'Name', 'lanr')
```

Comment: Typically you would store the data in the database in its original unmodified state (with long lines) and if they need to be wrapped, wrap them on output in application code.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - you mean the lines can't be wrapped because there is no syntax for it? The file is used only to prefill the DB (which happens automagically through hibernate), so there is no wrapping in application code and they are not stored in the DB but in the test classpath. But as I write the files myself I would like some better readability.